# Javascript Array displaying new entries on the front instead of back

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have a table that I am trying to add an empty row to the end of. (Eventually I will add input boxes and allow saving)

```
<div ng-repeat="rule in model.rules">
    <table id="" datatable="ng" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-columns="dtColumns" class="table-bordered" style="margin-bottom: 2%">
        <caption>{{rule.CategoryName}}</caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Order</th>
                <th>Rule</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="subRule in rule.Rules">
                <td>{{subRule.Sequence}}</td>
                <td>{{subRule.Name}}</td>
                <td><button type="button" ng-click="removeRule($subRule)" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="addRule(rule)">Add Rule</button>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.addRule = function (rule) {
    rule.Rules.push({ key: rule.Rules.length });
    console.log(rule.Rules);
};
```

Before the click:

[image: Before]

After the click:

[image]

As you can see the empty TR is popped to the front of the array on the page but:

[image: Console Array]

The array has the data in the right order, the screen just puts them in the front.

Why aren't the new tr's added to the end of the table?

Comment: Weird... it should be iterating in that order... try sticking an `orderBy` clause on your repeater.

Comment: @tymeJV I think that is the right Idea, but since I am adding an empty one it is still putting it on the front. I guess " " comes before 1?

Comment: Why you don;t push inside `$scope.rule` instead of updating its refernce `rule`

Comment: @pankajparkar That still has the same problem. It is not appending to the end of the list

Comment: then you use rely on filter orderby `Id`

Comment: @tymeJV You led me down the right path. I auto incremented the order and then ordered by the sequence. If you want to put that as an answer I will accept it.